# Generic method return generic type

Tags: java, generics

I have a `SimpleMapper` which has a constructor taking `ResultSet` as param:

```
public abstract class SimpleMapper{
    public SimpleMapper() {}

    public SimpleMapper(ResultSet rs) {}
}
```

...and I have several subclass from `SimpleMapper`.

Now I want to write a generic method, converting `ResultSet` to `List<T>` where `T` is subclass of `SimpleMapper`.

Here is the code:

```
    public static <T extends SimpleMapper> List<T> resultSetToList(ResultSet rs, Class<? extends SimpleMapper> clazz) throws SQLException {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            list.add(clazz.getConstructor(new Class[]{ResultSet.class}).newInstance(rs));
        }
        return list;
    }
```

The compiler is giving this error:

```
The method add(T) in the type List<T> is not applicable for the arguments (capture#2-of ? extends SimpleMapper)
```

What am I doing wrong here? I've specified `T` to be subclass of `SimlpeMapper`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than taking a `Class<? extends SimpleMapper>`, you should take a `Class<T>`. This makes sure that the class' constructor produces the same type as the type of list that you are returning:

```
public static <T extends SimpleMapper> List<T> resultSetToList(ResultSet rs, Class<T> clazz) 
    throws SQLException {
    try {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            list.add(clazz.getConstructor(ResultSet.class).newInstance(rs));
        }
        return list;
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
        // handle the exception in some way...
        // maybe rethrow a RuntimeException?
        throw new RuntimeException("Exception occurred during reflection!", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank, that works for me. A new problem comes up is that there're several unhandled exception warnings:
NoSuchMethodExceptionJava,InstantiationException,IllegalAccessException,InvocationTargetException.     
In this example I think I know what I'm doing since the generic type T already bounded to subclass of SimpleMapper, so should I just suppress those uncheck exceptions?

Comment: @ZiqiLiu Those are _checked_ exceptions. You need to catch it in some way or another. You can use a `try...catch` block, or let the caller handle it by adding to the `throws` clause. See my edit. "I know what I'm doing since the generic type T already bounded to subclass of SimpleMapper" <--- checked exceptions don't care. You still have to handle them. Plus, generics are erased at runtime - it is still _possible_ to pass something totally unexpected to the method, e.g. `String.class`, if one _really_ wanted.